# Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting

Tags: openssl, mqtt, tls1.2, esp32

I am trying to establish a secure connection(tls & open ssl certificates) from ESP32 to the MQTT broker on Raspberry Pi using pubsubclient & Wificlientsecure, but I am getting a socket error as shown below:

MQTT Console:

```
1582138400: New connection from 192.168.4.9 on port 8883.
1582138405: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
1582138413: New connection from 192.168.4.9 on port 8883.
1582138405: Socket error on client <unknown>, disconnecting.
```

Here is the conf file - /etc/mosquitto/mosquitto.conf:

```
persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/
#log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log
include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d
port 8883
allow_anonymous true
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
#tls_version tlsv1.2
```

Arduino Code:

```
#include <PubSubClient.h>
#include <SPIFFS.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_BMP085.h>
#define DHTPIN 4 // Digital pin connected to the DHT sensor
#define DHTTYPE DHT11 // DHT 11
#define wifi_ssid "MGK-RP-1" //wifi ssid
#define wifi_password "naht" //wifi password
const char* ca_cert =
"-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n"
"MIIEAjCCAuqgAwIBAgIJAM0HTvv4E6FaMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMIGVMQswCQYD\n"
"VQQGEwJpbjESMBAGA1UECAwJdGFtaWxuYWR1MRMwEQYDVQQHDApjb2ltYmF0b3Jl\n"
"MQwwCgYDVQQKDANtZ2sxETAPBgNVBAsMCGJ1aWxkaW90MRQwEgYDVQQDDAsxOTIu\n"
"MTY4LjQuMTEmMCQGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYXcmFta3VtYXIubWdrMUBnbWFpbC5jb20w\n"
"HhcNMjAwMjI4MDY1NTIxWhcNMjUwMjI3MDY1NTIxWjCBlTELMAkGA1UEBhMCaW4x\n"
"EjAQBgNVBAgMCXRhbWlsbmFkdTETMBEGA1UEBwwKY29pbWJhdG9yZTEMMAoGA1UE\n"
"JjAkBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWF3JhbWt1bWFyLm1nazFAZ21haWwuY29tMIIBIjANBgkq\n"
"hkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtmbO3kNK6lmYAGhAt8n8yziPNYZ1wLhs\n"
"3W/VkIm5A2veyHz8PivnknVdATx9/fRJ1cy1LKD/Wo5cwaH8dyKiVq/iRYZ4zAxq\n"
"s8va5xUkWlXoiGcB87wCviAGsdNXLa54/qPPa04T5vlaBr+Ht5gsQvB1OeRyTo8U\n"
"mD7VSw9eCBMlBpTZprlHReXLcnBOvNQ/9n0vN/KmdJXXu2ZNGj8P/itbFlRpKBAP\n"
"2AxUJAiNHAB7No7WZ4mMLPxp6iJbDb6KUVH0vwMgVHq4tkWNEcMcnUPRemkiA321\n"
"1oJRxBQY26xd7AXbTass9UqIRF1R1kb29pZqkwarfVAgqalegd8W6wIDAQABo1Mw\n"
"UTAdBgNVHQ4EFgQUHZBuhBeUW9UhnQQ5AWdmQffukPowHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUHZBu\n"
"hBeUW9UhnQQ5AWdmQffukPowDwYDVR0TAQH/BAUwAwEB/zANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsF\n"
"AAOCAQEAC6buT/r7oJiLhgWnU5QrSPFbuX6vViN6//wk1Jz3SZLP/qgfv1UgHXmX\n"
"hGHtse45S9V3ke7isI6IQ2QQpLaCg2NpQoEqXy2E3zUForElRuB2NWy6OT2+fglL\n"
"wWJ2f7STaGJcTUAxwB4R5pfNycTR+jg3l3pNuosnq85E0zSUnvMPPNilM7JooWQ5\n"
"bFixSJUx7rknyRjvD+5X7umyB+rWhv/VdogcKvln3dL70yS3ujWatTVYkUKirdL/\n"
"8MiM2wxi5pSV9PRmiJxbCVRryKMJ05ZELndmjRLtU/0kwKthENkV0pL1n81UqeIu\n"
"PtkIMHm89cGiKmM+pZpCDVcqAN8bWg==\n"
"-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";
#define mqtt_server "192.168.4.1" // server name or IP
#define temperature_topic "temphum" //Topic temperature
#define atmos_pre_topic "atmos_pre"
#define light_lux_topic "light_lux"
//#define humidity_topic "humid1" //Topic humidity
#define debug_topic "debug"
bool debug = true;

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);
Adafruit_BMP085 bmp;
int sensorPin = 36; //
float rawRange = 4096;
float logRange = 5.0;
/* create an instance of WiFiClientSecure */
WiFiClientSecure espClient;
PubSubClient client(espClient);

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println(ca_cert);
    setup_wifi(); //Connect to Wifi network
    espClient.setCACert(ca_cert);
    client.setServer(mqtt_server, 8883); // Configure MQTT connection, change port if needed.
    if (!client.connected()) {
        reconnect();
    }
    if (!bmp.begin()) {
       Serial.println("Could not find a valid BMP085/BMP180 sensor, check wiring!");
       while (1) {}
    }
    dht.begin();
}
void loop() {
    delay(2000);
    float h = dht.readHumidity();
    float t = dht.readTemperature();
    float f = dht.readTemperature(true);
    String tempe = String(t).c_str();
    String hum = String(h).c_str();
    if (isnan(h) || isnan(t) || isnan(f)) {
        Serial.println(F("Failed to read from DHT sensor!"));
        return;
    }
    float hif = dht.computeHeatIndex(f, h);
    float hic = dht.computeHeatIndex(t, h, false);
    String heat = String(hic).c_str();
    String temphum = tempe+","+hum+","+heat;
    float P = bmp.readPressure();
    float temp = bmp.readTemperature();
    String pre = String(P).c_str();
    String atmos_pre = pre+","+String(temp).c_str();
    int rawValue = analogRead(sensorPin);
    String light_lux = String(RawToLux(rawValue)).c_str();
    Serial.println();
    delay(500);
    if ( debug ) {
        Serial.print("Temperature : ");
        Serial.print(t);
        Serial.print(" | Humidity : ");
        Serial.println(h);
    }
    // Publish values to MQTT topics
    client.publish(temperature_topic, String(temphum).c_str(), false);
    client.publish(atmos_pre_topic, String(atmos_pre).c_str(), false);
    client.publish(light_lux_topic, String(light_lux).c_str(), false);
    if ( debug ) {
       Serial.println("data sent to MQTT.");
    }
}

float RawToLux(int raw)
{
    float logLux = raw * logRange / rawRange;
    Serial.print("loglux");
    Serial.print(logLux);
    return pow(10, logLux);
}

//Setup connection to wifi
void setup_wifi() {
    delay(20);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("Connecting to ");
    Serial.println(wifi_ssid);
    //WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    WiFi.begin(wifi_ssid, wifi_password);
    while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
        delay(100);
        Serial.print(".");
    }
    Serial.println("");
    Serial.println("WiFi is OK ");
    Serial.print("=> ESP32 new IP address is: ");
    Serial.print(WiFi.localIP());
    Serial.println("");
}

//Reconnect to wifi if connection is lost
void reconnect() {
    while (!client.connected()) {
        Serial.print("Connecting to MQTT broker ...");
        if (client.connect("ESP32Client",0,2,0,0)) {
            Serial.println("OK");
        } else {
            Serial.print("[Error] Not connected: ");
            Serial.println(client.state());
            Serial.println("Wait 5 seconds before retry.");
            delay(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

The pubsubclient connects to the network but I get a -2 error code from the client.state() function. Can you help me rectify this error and establish a secure connection.

Comment: A connect message with an immediate disconnect from client <unknown> is almost always a client authentication issue of some sort.  I don't see your 'client.connect()' call in setup() either.  rc = -2 I believe is a cert error....it doesn't like your cert.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call PubSubClient's `loop()` method in `loop()`; otherwise it doesn't get to perform necessary housekeeping functions and keep the connection alive.

So your loop function should start like this:

```
void loop() {
  client.loop();

  delay(2000);
```

PubSubClient sends a "keepalive" message to the broker once every 15 seconds (by default) so you need to be careful about using `delay()` functions in `loop()`. The way your code is written right now it should be okay, but if you increase the delays by much they may interfere with the keepalives and cause the connection to close.